# Combine prefetch_related and annotate in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-queryset

I have three models

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=100)

class ModelB(models.Model):
    modela = ForeignKey(ModelA)

class ModelC(models.Model):
    modelb = ForeignKey(ModelB)
    amount = IntegerField()
```

I can get the output

```
name, number of model c objects
==============
Some name, 312
Another name, 17
```

With the queryset

```
ModelA.objects.all().prefetch_related('modelb_set', 'groupb_set__modelc_set')
```

and template

```
{% for modela in modela_list %}
    {% for modelb in modela.modelb_set.all %}
        {{ modelb }}, {{ modelb.modelc_set.count }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Instead of counting the number of ModelC objects connected to each ModelB object I want to sum the amount field in ModelC.

I don't know how to combine `prefetch_related` and `annotate` in my queryset, but it must be something like

```
(ModelA.objects.all()
       .prefetch_related('modelb_set', 'groupb_set__modelc_set')
       .annotate(total_amount=Sum('modelc_set__amount')))
```

Comment: I don't think this is currently possible. For my use case I was able to break it up into two separate queries by running annotate on only the related set. However your use case is slightly more complicated since you're starting with a queryset and not a single object.

Comment: I don't think the annotate is necessary in any way here. You have fully prefetched modelb_set and its related modelc_set. What you want is do a python implementation of `len(modelb.modelc_set.all())`, maybe in the context, maybe a method on the model for use in templates. Provided you did it right, this shouldn't trigger an additional query because that list is fully loaded into memory. Even using the `.count()` syntax may not trigger a query, but this depends on the implementation within Django.

Answer (score 10):

I think you should be able to achieve that by doing this:

```py
from django.db.models import F, Sum

(ModelA.objects.all()
    .prefetch_related('modelb_set', 'modelb__modelc_set')\
    .values('name')\  # group values by modela.name, read: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/
    .annotate(name = F('name'),
              total_amount = Sum('modelb__modelc__amount')))
```

and in your template you should use:

```
{% for modela in modela_list %}
    {{ modela.name }}, {{ modela.total_amount }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this down to:

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

ModelA.objects.all()
    .prefetch_related('modelb__modelc_set') \
    .values('name') \
    .annotate(name=F('name'), total_amount=Sum('modelb__modelc__amount'))
```

I know this works in later versions of Django.

Answer (score 0):

i did it by using django internals to check if related queryset is evaluated / prefetched

```
from django.db.models import Sum, QuerySet, Model


def is_evaluated_queryset(qs):
    return isinstance(qs, QuerySet) and qs._result_cache is not None


class Order(Model):
    """Order can have multiple payments"""
    
    def get_total_payment(self):
        """ returns sum of all the payments for this order"""

        payments_qs = self.payment_set.all()
        if is_evaluated_queryset(payments_qs):
            # qs is prefetched - better not to use aggregate
            return sum(payment.amount for payment in payments_qs)
        else:
            return payments_qs.aggregate(total=Sum('amount'))['total'] or 0
```